# This webpage has a redirect loop occurance

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My wordpress website was crashed due to addition of script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var myCallback = function( myParam ) {
  alert( "this was called across domains!" );
  };
  </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://crossdomainhost/CrossDomainConsumerSite/Default.aspx?callback=myCallback&param=myParam></script>
```

I removed the script from my code but now the website is still not working. Do anyone has a solution for this?
on opening webpage, it shows-->

```
 This webpage has a redirect loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drive yourself crazy trying to understand what code is being added to your Wordpress site and how it's causing loops, etc.  The easiest and best solution to a Wordpress site getting hacked is to do the following:

1. Change all your passwords, including Wordpress admin and your hosting account control panel, ftp, and any other passwords.
2. Reinstall Wordpress from the latest version.
3. Upgrade to the latest version of the Wordpress theme you're using.
4. Get rid of all themes you don't currently have active.

This happened to me before and I got frustrated that my hosting provider couldn't help me at all, in fact they were threatening to cancel my account because phishing attempts were originating from my site.  So, I left the hosting provider and wrote a bunch of scripts to figure out how I was getting hacked.  Bottom line is that I didn't find out much at all, but my site is fully restored now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:
- Download the WP version from WP svn which match with your version
- Replace the wp-content directory with yours
- Replace htaccess file and index.php file
try to access now